# Transition probability in the case of "strong" perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

We know that Fermi's Golden rule is true only for weak and short perturbation, when the transition probability $P_{fi}\ll 1$. But what if perturbation is relatively strong, so we can't use this formula? Should we use different approach in this case of strong perturbation or we can't even use PT anymore?

To be more specific, I'm studying interaction between photons and phonons and in several cases probability of photon transition become quiet large, so result seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Have you investigated how to derive the golden rule from first principles? If you do that, the answer to this question will appear.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, I did the calculation to understand all the "features" in formula, but still some questions remain. In particular we are dealing with the equation $\frac{\partial a_{f}(t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}\sum_{k}a_{k}(t)W_{fk}(t)e^{i\omega_{fk}t}$, we initially asume that in zero order of PT our coefficient $a_{k}^{(0)}$ remain unchanged (equal to 1) due to little perturbation. But can we assume that our probability amplitude is not constant, but changes in time somehow? For instance, like $\sim e^{-\frac{t}{T}}$, if T (lifetime of the initial state) is big enough.

Comment: **edit**: if T (lifetime of the initial state) is _small_ enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. That is why in the strong laser light field, the golden rule is gave up.

Comment: What approach is using in this case? For example, in scattering/diffraction of light problems?